# how to get currency sign to display in a view panel xpages

Tags: xpages

I have a column in an xpage that I want to display the currency symbol with the value. In the underlying Notes View it is displaying. I have tried both the view panel and the dynamic view but neither display the $ symbol. It just displays the number. Also if it is an integer number ($100.00) it just displays 100. I want it to display trailing zeros after decimal place along with the currency symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view control you can set the view column's "Display Type" to "Number" and then "Display format" to "Currency". This would enable you to set the Currency symbol of your choice and format it accordingly. So your view column's code would look something like this:

```
<xp:viewColumn columnName="price" id="viewColumn4">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" minFractionDigits="2" type="currency"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Price" id="viewColumnHeader4"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

In above example `price` is stored as number.